# Is there luggage storage available near Venice train station?

Tags: trains, italy, luggage-storage, venice

I am taking a night train from Venice so I need a place to keep my luggage until then. 
Is there a luggage center at Venice station? 
If so, now much does it cost and when is it open?

Comment: This is the first hit on google: http://europeforvisitors.com/venice/articles/venice-left-luggage.htm Are you departing from Venezia Mestre or Venezia Santa Lucia (in the lagoon)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are departing from Venezia Santa Lucia, [there is a left-luggage office near track 1.](http://www.grandistazioni.it/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=09dd82a9ec4eb110VgnVCM1000003f16f90aRCRD)

Opening hours are from 6 am till 11 pm and cost is

> **Charges**
>   6,00 € the first 5 hours
>   0,90 € /hour from 6th to 12th hour
>   0,40 € /hour from 13th hour on

If possible however, you should try to ask your hotel if they can store your luggage for you until the evening, which will likely cost you nothing or a much smaller fee.

[This article](http://europeforvisitors.com/venice/articles/venice-left-luggage.htm) recommends [a slightly cheaper place near the station](http://europeforvisitors.com/venice/articles/keep-calm-point.htm) which is open until 7 pm only. There are also further options listed within easy reach in Piazzale Roma.